# Awaiting transaction in the mempool

Tags: python-3.x, ganache, brownie

I am trying to follow Curve tutorial on Brownie. After installing Ganache and Brownie successfully I have tried to use the token template from https://github.com/brownie-mix by typing `brownie bake token` in the command line (while being in the project's folder). The structure of the token project got re-created in my directory. After typing `brownie console` I get response that `brownie environment is ready`. Then I try to deply token contract with `Token.deploy("Test Token", "TST", 18, 1e21, {'from': accounts[0]})` and this command resulted with mesaage "`Awaiting transaction in the mempool`"- This message has been hanging on for over 30 minutes I am wondering how should I de-bug it? What can cause the situation where the token does not get deployed correctly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe I can help you.
Let's go.
Your problem is with `gas_price`, in a recent eth version the gas is always necessary.

I resolved my problem with this way...

```
from brownie import accounts, config, SimpleStorage
from brownie.network import gas_price
from brownie.network.gas.strategies import LinearScalingStrategy

gas_strategy = LinearScalingStrategy("60 gwei", "70 gwei", 1.1)

gas_price(gas_strategy)

def deploy_simple_storage():
    account = accounts[0]
    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({
        "from": account,
        "gas_price": gas_strategy
        })

    # Transact
    # Call
    print(simple_storage)


def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

I don't know if need all this for your problem, but I needed. try import `gas_price` and call it after `"from": account`.

If someone have a better solution, tell me pls.

fonts:
https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html
https://github.com/batprem/pynft

Comment: Thank you! I will test this solution and let you know if that solved the issue

Comment: Thanks, I resolved without gas_price(gas_strategy), keep worthing with all code without this part.

Answer (score 0):

As I encountered the same issue I have tried around and realized that when deploying to a live net a default gas price setting seems to be set meaning  only ganache needs the above described variables and imports etc.

It actually seems to be working better when setting these variables ONLY for development nets and the `"gas_price": gas_strategy` in the contract deployment dictionary seems unnecessary for both.

I have used an "if on dev" check to set `gas_price(gas_strategy)` see below:

```
from brownie.network import gas_price
from brownie.network.gas.strategies import LinearScalingStrategy

gas_strategy = LinearScalingStrategy("60 gwei", "70 gwei", 1.1)

if network.show_active() == "development":
    gas_price(gas_strategy)
```

(Solidity version 0.6.6 and this was just trial and error so no official fix)